# Using an F# type provider to instantiate types and present them as properties

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'd like to do the following:

`let allTypes = AllTypes (t, assemblies)`

... where `AllTypes` is a type provider, the properties of which are instances of all types in the given array of assemblies that subclass type `t`.  (All of the types have a single constructor that takes no arguments.)

Is this doable using F# type providers?  I have no experience creating my own provider, and I don't want to waste my time attempting to do this if it isn't feasible.

I'd greatly appreciate any links to pages that would get me started coding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a lot of activity going on in the [FSharp.Data](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data) github repo.  There is a learning curve, but tuning into that repo might be useful.

Beyond that, this intro [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh361034.aspx) covers some of the basics, and here's a [Type Provider starter pack](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack) that's been prepared by the F# open source community.

The [fsharp.org](http://fsharp.org) site, and this [projects page](http://fsharp.org/community/projects/) covers a cross-section of what's going on (including type providers).

You could take the list that Mark suggests here and turn it into a type provider.  I think an exploratory way of interacting with namespaces would be useful.  Why not?  I'd use it.  Please publish on GitHub if you get around to it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a type provider for that; you can write that code using basic reflection:

```
open System.Reflection

let allTypes (baseClass : Type) (assemblies : Assembly seq) =
    assemblies
    |> Seq.collect (fun x -> x.GetExportedTypes())
    |> Seq.filter (fun x -> baseClass.IsAssignableFrom x)
    |> Seq.collect (fun x -> x.GetConstructors())
    |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.GetParameters().Length = 0)
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Invoke([||]))
```

The `allTypes` function has this signature: `Type -> Assembly seq -> obj seq`.

Comment: Yes, I could do something like that (and I've already written that part of the code, in fact).

The thing is, I want the types to be exposed as *properties*, to take advantage of compile-time resolution of those values.  (Not having to cast them, Intellisense pop-up, etc.)

Comment: What do you mean by *properties*?

Comment: @MiloDC It may just be me, but it's not clear to me how properties relates to a list of objects that derive from a base class...

Comment: instead of a property of a class that returns a list of objects, imagine one property per object.  There are a few advantages: heterogeneous types, knowing the types at compile time, Intellisense reveals, not having to instance them, et al.